# Using input file to create an object and add that said object into an array, and have it print out the information on that array

Tags: java, oop

Here is my code that takes in a text file and creates an Account object, what I am having trouble with is printing out the account objects that are in the the banks array of accounts

```
  public static void main (String[] args)
   {
      try {

          // Read data from a file into a Bank.
          // Each line of the file has info for one account.  
          BankInterface myBank = readFromFile("BankAccounts.txt");

          // Print all the data stored in the bank.
          System.out.println (myBank);

      } // end try  
      catch (IOException ioe) {
         System.out.println("IOException in main: " + ioe.getMessage()); 
         ioe.printStackTrace();
      } // end catch
      catch (Exception e) {
         System.out.println("Exception in main: " + e.getMessage());
         e.printStackTrace();
      } // end catch
   } // end main


   /**
    * readFromFile:    **** INSERT COMMENTS ****
    * 
    */
   public static BankInterface readFromFile (String fileName) throws IOException
   {
       // Creata a bank.
       BankInterface myBank = new Bank("Bank");

         // Open a file for reading.
         Scanner inputSource = new Scanner (new File(fileName));

         // while there are more tokens to read from the input source...
     while (inputSource.hasNext()) {

        // Read one line of input from the file into an Account object
            Account acct = InputManager.readOneAccountFrom (inputSource);
        // Store the account info in the bank.
        //**** INSERT CODE TO ADD acct TO THE BANK ****
        myBank.addAccount(acct);

     } // end while


         return myBank;

    } // end readFromFile
```

When I run the main I am not getting the accounts to print out I just get:

```
Reading: name,id,balance
Exception in main: null
```

Can someone explain why this is happening and how to fix it? 
StackTrace:

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:862)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1371)
    at InputManager.readOneAccountFrom(InputManager.java:30)
    at ATM.readFromFile(ATM.java:48)
    at ATM.main(ATM.java:15)
    at __SHELL3.run(__SHELL3.java:6)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at bluej.runtime.ExecServer$3.run(ExecServer.java:730)
```

Here is the readOneAccountFrom method:

```
public static Account readOneAccountFrom (Scanner inputSource)
{
    // Read one line of account data into oneLine
    System.out.println ("Reading: name,id,balance");
    String oneLine = inputSource.nextLine();

    // Parse line of account data, separated by commas.
    Scanner lineTokenizer = new Scanner (oneLine);
    lineTokenizer.useDelimiter (",");

    // Get account data (i.e. name, accountNum and balance) from oneLine
    String name = lineTokenizer.next ();
    String accountNum = lineTokenizer.next ();
    Money balance = new Money(lineTokenizer.nextLong());

    // Create and return an Account object with the data read for one   account.
    Account oneAccount = new Account (name, accountNum, balance);
    System.out.println ("Account read: " + oneAccount);

    return oneAccount;
} // end readOneAccountFrom
```

Comment: What is the stacktrace?

Comment: To ease debugging, disable `catch` blocks that are not required, such as those handling unchecked exceptions. The code in your second `catch` block is wasting important context information necessary for debugging.

Comment: The problem is in the ```readOneAccountFrom``` method, you're taking information from the scanner, but it doesn't have any. [The documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNext--) says when such exceptions are thrown.

Comment: I posted the readOneAccountFrom method what could be the error?

Answer (score 0):

Even though your comment says

// Read one line of input from the file into an Account object

you are not reading line correctly.

You should be using the hasNextLine() and nextLine() to read a line from the Scanner. Something like below:

```
while (inputSource.hasNextLine()) {
      String line = inputSource.nextLine();
```

Comment: I did that and the output remains the same

Comment: looks you are running out of tokens as the exception is at scanner.next().  Try printing the line you read from the file (which is variable oneLine in your example)